# GridView onClickListener/onItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am trying to implement a Card view inside grid view. The grid view is showing perfectly; even when I touch on a grid view item it's showing nothing. But when I click on the text which is display below its work. I referred [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401778/gridview-onclick-listener-its-not-working) but not working...

Thanks.

My code is as below,

// Contact_Backup.java

```
public class Contact_Backup extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Bind(R.id.gridview)
        GridView gridview;
        String[] contact_screen_array;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.contact_backup);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);
            contact_screen_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TextScreen);
            String[] contact_icon_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.IconScreen);
            String concat = "\nContacts";
            gridview.setAdapter(new Custom_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),contact_icon_array,contact_screen_array,concat));
        }
    }
```

//Custom_Adapter

```
public class Custom_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context contaxt;
    String[] Array_text;
    String[] Array_icon;
    String concat;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Custom_Adapter(Context context,String[] Array_icon, String[] Array_text, String concat)
    {
        this.contaxt = context;
        this.Array_text = Array_text;
        this.Array_icon = Array_icon;
        this.concat=concat;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Array_text.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Bind(R.id.Screen_icon)
    Button Screen_icon;
    @Bind(R.id.Screen_text)
    TextView Screen_text;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) contaxt
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(contaxt);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_app_card_layout, null);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, grid);
            Screen_text.setText(Array_text[position]+concat);
            Screen_icon.setText(Array_icon[position]);
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(contaxt.getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
            Screen_icon.setTypeface(font);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        grid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("TAG::",""+position);
            }
        });
        return grid;
    }
}
```

// contact_backup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_backgorund"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:padding="5.0dip"
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_screen"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/newclr"
            android:id="@+id/tvContacts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/contacts"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1.0"
            android:shadowDy="1.0"
            android:shadowRadius="2.0"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/newclr"
            android:id="@+id/tvLastBackup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/last_backup"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1.0"
            android:shadowDy="1.0"
            android:shadowRadius="2.0"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar_screen"
        android:background="@color/newclr"/>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_below="@+id/v1"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:paddingRight="10sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </GridLayout>

    <!-- com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner
        android:id="@+id/startAppBanner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /-->


</RelativeLayout>
```

// new_app_card_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fssr_card"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/Contacts_Button_Layout"
        android:background="@drawable/linearlayout_normal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-1.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        >

        <Button
            android:textSize="35.0sp"
            android:textColor="@color/newclr"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/Screen_icon"
            android:background="@null"
            android:padding="20sp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fa_icon_contact"
            android:drawablePadding="5.0dip"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="15.0sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/Screen_text"
            android:background="@color/newclr"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/contactsbackup"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this method for clicking on a gridview item:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // your action when gridView item is clicked   

        }
    });
```

Comment: @JigneshM.Mehta what do you mean not working? what do you want to do after cell clicked? be sure you call the onITEMclicklistener in the activity, which your gridview exists.

Comment: buddy, thanks for the help. It is not actually a problem. My problem is I used Button inside Custom Grid. When I click on a Grid then the code of Grid is overridden by Button click, so that will not work as fine as I want. I use Textview instead of Button. then I 'll work fine. by the way thanks for the help. n your code is also working fine now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the listener on the actual `gridview` object. 

`gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()...);`

Comment: I try it in the  Contact_Backup.java Class But That code has not effected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 public class Contact_Backup extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Bind(R.id.gridview)
        GridView gridview;
        String[] contact_screen_array;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.contact_backup);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);
            contact_screen_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TextScreen);
            String[] contact_icon_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.IconScreen);
            String concat = "\nContacts";
            gridview.setAdapter(new Custom_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),contact_icon_array,contact_screen_array,concat));
            gridview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for(int i=0;i<contact_screen_array.length;i++) {
                        Log.d("TAG::", "Position"+contact_screen_array[i]);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove listener from adapter class and use it in activity

Comment: I tried but it is not working buddy... it only work when I click on contact_screen_array Textview....

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I succeed. here is the code.

Just use Textview instead of Button in // new_app_card_layout.xml.

Just Update it,

```
<TextView
        android:textSize="35.0sp"
        android:textColor="@color/newclr"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/Screen_icon"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="20sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fa_icon_contact"
        android:drawablePadding="5.0dip"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Thank You so much, All of you for help... :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this i have updated your **custom Adapter** class.please check again with this updated code.

```
public class Custom_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context contaxt;
    String[] Array_text;
    String[] Array_icon;
    String concat;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Custom_Adapter(Context context,String[] Array_icon, String[] Array_text, String concat)
    {
        this.contaxt = context;
        this.Array_text = Array_text;
        this.Array_icon = Array_icon;
        this.concat=concat;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Array_text.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Bind(R.id.Screen_icon)
    Button Screen_icon;
    @Bind(R.id.Screen_text)
    TextView Screen_text;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) contaxt
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(contaxt);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_app_card_layout, null);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, grid);
            Screen_text.setText(Array_text[position]+concat);
            Screen_icon.setText(Array_icon[position]);
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(contaxt.getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
            Screen_icon.setTypeface(font);

            grid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("TAG::",""+position);
                }
            });

        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;

            grid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("TAG::",""+position);
                }
            });
        }
        return grid;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you out !

Comment: I tried but it is not working buddy... the same problem occurs it only work when I click on contact_screen_array Textview....

Comment: you want the same done with " android:id="@+id/Screen_icon" " this button ??

Comment: yes. may it not work just because "android:id="@+id/Screen_icon" is Button ??

Comment: i am gonna update my code and add toast message on clicking this button will that be ok ?

Comment: I got the problem buddy... I use Button and just click on that so there is no effect... I just update it with text view. it works fine now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132158/discussion-between-jignesh-m-mehta-and-apoorv-mehrotra).